# Uncaught TypeError javascript Canot read property ''username'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I run my Javascript I'm getting this error:

> KinveyRequester.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

And I don't know how do fix it

Code:

```
function registerUser(e) { 
    registerAjax(e); 
    registerSuccess();
    // window.location = "Items.html";
} 

function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
}

function saveAuthInSession(userInfo) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("username", userInfo.username);
    sessionStorage.setItem("authToken", userInfo._kmd.authtoken);

    $("#loggedInUser").text("Welcome, " + userInfo.username);
}

function registerAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let userData = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: userData,
        success: registerSuccess,
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

Comment: Consider putting your code into a linting tool. You have a number of syntax errors.

Comment: Seems you never call `saveAuthSession` here?

Comment: It should be userData, not userInfo.

Comment: @pshep123 userInfo is a function parameter here, problem is the function is never called.

Comment: registerAjax is not closed...

Comment: Voting to close this question as it's full of typos.

Comment: The function is called in the other js file

Here:

function registerUser(e) {
    registerAjax(e);
    registerSuccess();
    //window.location = "Items.html";
}
function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
}

Comment: Your 'userData' is scoped to the registerAjax function but looks like you're trying to use it outside that scope without passing it.  ie registerSuccess is called with the data from the POST, not from some other random variables.   What does your POST return?

Comment: registerSuccess() is looking for a parameter, but you're not passing one.

Comment: So how can i fix it ?

Comment: You are calling registerSuccess twice (from registerUser and success callback), shouldn't you just do it only once after ajax success?

Comment: The POST request creates a username withour problems

Comment: This is the second question I've seen from you @RumenPanchev which shows you're just not understanding basic JavaScript syntax. You might want to consider learning more of those basics before writing code like this, and perhaps before asking more questions on SO. We do like when people research a question before asking. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You do not call `registerSuccess` with userData (or any param), so 'userInfo' parameter will always be undefined.

You can make two changes

- remove from registerUser as that would run before ajax has completed
- pass userData in the success

ie:

```
success: function() {
    registerSuccess(userData);
});
```

I don't use `let` yet as it's not backward compatible, but this will certainly work if you change it to 'var userData'

Updated code:

```
function registerUser(e) { 
    registerAjax(e); 
    // do not call here - this will run before the ajax has completed: registerSuccess();
    // window.location = "Items.html";
} 

function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
}

function saveAuthInSession(userInfo) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("username", userInfo.username);
    sessionStorage.setItem("authToken", userInfo._kmd.authtoken);

    $("#loggedInUser").text("Welcome, " + userInfo.username);
}

function registerAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userData = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: userData,
        success: function() { 
            // this will keep the scope of userData above and pass on success
            registerSuccess(userData); 
        },
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

---

of course, you'll immediately get the next problem:

```
 userInfo._kmd.authtoken
```

as _kmd.authtoken is not part of userData

So it all depends on what you get back from the POST, ie

```
success: function(responseData) { 
    console.log(responseData);
    registerSuccess(responseData);
}
```

Comment: @Endless See update at the end, already noticed that.  It's not clear if that will then be a problem or not.

Comment: Now it's working, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

The reeasons for this error is `userInfo` is undefined so Javascript is unable to find the property 'username' of `userInfo` because `userInfo` is `undefined`
Please tell when are you calling this function saveAuthInSession???

```
function registerAjax(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userData = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + "user/" + kinveyAppKey + "/",
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: userData,
        success: function() { 
            registerSuccess(userData); 
        },
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

Call that function here

Comment: Here:

function registerSuccess(userInfo) {
    saveAuthInSession(userInfo);
    showInfo('User registration successful.');
}

Comment: When are you calling registerSuccess??

Comment: Here

function registerUser(e) {
    registerAjax(e);
    registerSuccess();
    //window.location = "Items.html";
}

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: Your javascript is running asynchronously so before getting your ajax result registerSuccess this method is called..

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if it would be easier for you to just reduce the number of functions you are calling...

```
function registerUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var userData = {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: kinveyBaseUrl + 'user/' + kinveyAppKey + '/',
        headers: kinveyAppAuthHeaders,
        data: userData,
        success: function(responseData) {
            showInfo('User registration successful.');
            sessionStorage.setItem('username', userInfo.username);
            sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', userInfo._kmd.authtoken);
            // sessionStorage.setItem('authToken', responseData._kmd.authtoken); ?
            // window.location = "Items.html";
            $('#loggedInUser').text('Welcome, ' + userInfo.username);
        },
        error: handleAjaxError
    });
}
```

Comment: Where's `userInfo` defined?  Should that be `userData` or `responseData` ?